# C# Replace leading apostrophe Excel COM

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

How can I remove leading apostrophe of a cell (or range) in Excel?

i.e.:

[image: Cell value]

Tried the following values but all of them doesn't include the leading apostrophe:

```
xlRange.Value
xlRange.Value2
xlRange.get_Value(Type.Missing)
```

Also tried using the replace code below but didn't work:

```
xlRange.Replace("'", "", Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

xlRange.NumberFormat returns "General"

Comment: It is not actually in the cell value, just a convenient shortcut for the user to enter a text label instead of data.  Check out the [PrefixCharacter property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_PrefixCharacter) for a possible way to detect it.  Use Clear() and reassign the Value to turn it into data.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a leading apostrophe with numeric values in Excel is to mark the content as "text", which also aligns it to the left as a result. This can be seen by querying the cell content in the Immediate Window of the VBA Editor (Ctrl+G):

```
?ActiveCell.Value
```

If this is performed on text (with apostrophe) the result is flush at the left side of the window. When performed on a number a space precedes the result.

Converting the cell content to a number removes the apostrophe. Trying to do this to non-numeric content results in an error. The following code demonstrates how this can be done in VB-speak:

```
Sub ConvertLeftAlignedNumber()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim rngVal As Variant

    Set rng = xlApp.ActiveCell
    rngVal = rng.Value
    If IsNumeric(rngVal) Then
        rng.Value = Val(rngVal)
    End If
End Sub
```

In C# use `Double.TryParse()` instead of `IsNumeric`

If the problem is also to remove leading apostrophes from text as well as numbers this can be done for text values by assiging the text content to a variable, clearing the cell, then writing the value back.

```
    //test data
    Excel.Range rngString = ws.get_Range("B12", missing);        
    Excel.Range rngLeftValue = ws.get_Range("D14", missing);        
    Excel.Range rngValue = ws.get_Range("A15", missing);
    rngString.Value2 = "'test";
    rngLeftValue.Value2 = "'10";
    rngValue.Value2 = 10;

    //Is numeric?
    Double val;
    if (Double.TryParse(rngString.Value2.ToString(), out val))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(val.ToString());
    }
    else //it's a string
    {
        string sString = rngString.Text.ToString();
        rngString.Clear();
        string sStringx = sString.Substring(0);
        rngString.Value2 = sStringx;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(rngString.Value2.ToString());
    }
    if (Double.TryParse(rngLeftValue.Value2.ToString(), out val))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(val.ToString());
    }
    if (Double.TryParse(rngValue.Value2.ToString(), out val))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(val.ToString());
    }
```

In VB(A) the `Right` function can be used:

```
Dim s As String

s = CStr(ActiveCell.Value2)
ActiveCell.Clear
ActiveCell.Value2 = Right(s, 1)
```

Comment: My problem is not regarding numbers only but any data type.

Comment: The leading apostrophe tells Excel to treat the value as text. It's not related to alignment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah, OK. My brain had something like apostrophe = text + left; double-quote = text + right. But either that was an earlier version and is no longer applicable or my mental data was confused because I see that's no (or no longer) the case. I've corrected the text - thank you!

Comment: Okay but the problem is that the apostrophe appears on the Excel file but rng.Value2 doesn't include the leading apostrophe.

Comment: @GustavoKnx Yes, I'm aware of that. The apostrophe also isn't visible in the Excel cell, only in the formula bar. Excel is "masking" it / handling it like a control character, That's why work-arounds of this nature are required. You'll notice no one has asked you *why* you feel you need to remove these, it's just assumed you have a reason...